# JavaScriptSerializer deserializing to a nested object

Tags: c#, javascript, serialization, deserialization

I have an object (called an expression) that contains three parameters: term1 operation term2 where term1 and term2 are objects and operation is a string.  The logic handling the object can handle term1 or term2 being a string or recursive scenarios where they contain an embedded expression.

i.e.

```
[DataContract] public class expression
{
    [DataMember] public object term1 { get; set; }
    [DataMember] public string operation { get; set; }
    [DataMember] public object term2 { get; set; }
}
```

When I attempt to deserialize an object where term1/term2 are simple strings, it works great, i.e.

```
{ term1: "foo", operation: "=", term2: "bar" }
```

will deserialize correctly using the C# JavaScriptSerializer and the following code:

```
    public T deserialize_json<T>(string json_string)
    {
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        return (T)serializer.Deserialize<T>(json_string);
    }
```

However, when I attempt to submit a nested object, i.e.:

```
{ 
  term1: 
  { 
    term1: "foo", operation: "=", term2: "bar" 
  }, 
  operation: "or", 
  term2: 
  { 
    term1: "foo", operation: "equals", term2: "baz" 
  } 
}
```

The JavaScriptSerializer will deserialize term1 and term2 into `'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]'`

Any idea?

My method call is simple:

```
expression expr = deserialize<expression>(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to serialize information about type of term1 and term2. For that you can use Newtonsoft.Json library.

Try this code:

```
expression model = new expression() { term1 = new expression() { operation = " + " } };
string content = ModelManager<expression>.SaveToString(model);
/* content =
{
    "$type": "Test.expression, Test",
    "term1": {
    "$type": "Test.expression, Test",
    "operation": " + "
    }
}
*/
var model2 = ModelManager<expression>.LoadFromString(content);
string content2 = ModelManager<expression>.SaveToString(model2);
// content == content2 

public static class ModelManager<T>
{
    public static T LoadFromString(string content)
    {    
        using (var sr = new StringReader(content))
        using (var jr = new JsonTextReader(sr))
            return GetSerializer().Deserialize<T>(jr);
    }
    public static string SaveToString(T model)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(512);

        using (var sw = new StringWriter(sb, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        using (var jtw = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
            GetSerializer().Serialize(jtw, model);

        return sb.ToString();
    }

    private static Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer GetSerializer()
    {
        return new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer()
        {
            NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore,
            DefaultValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DefaultValueHandling.Include,
            TypeNameHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.TypeNameHandling.Objects,
            TypeNameAssemblyFormat = System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.FormatterAssemblyStyle.Simple,
            Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
            MaxDepth = null,
            ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Error,
            PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.None
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Correction: it didn't show term1 as null, worked fine for the non-nested case.  Same output for the nested case as before though.

Comment: I tested it. You had to make some mistake. Please try to use my test example (I extended the example just now).

Comment: I can't add type information in the JSON.  That's ... kind of a really bad hack.  I can't use that.

Comment: There is not other way unless you change you data structure or provide custom type resolver. You can declare term1 and term2 type as: class MyTerm { public string Value{ get; set; } public string Expression{ get; set; } }. And assign proper property.

Comment: Sorry, it should be: class MyTerm { public string Value { get; set; } public expression Exp { get; set; } }.